# Damped oscillator retarded Green function

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, greens-functions, dissipation

The Green function for the damped oscillator in Fourier space is
$\tilde{G}(\omega)=\frac1{\omega_0^2 -\omega^2 + 2i\gamma\omega}$,
where $\gamma$ is the damping parameter and $\omega_0$ the oscillator's natural frequency.  Standard contour analysis of the inverse FT of $\tilde{G}$ gives the retarded Green function in time, $$G(t,t')=\Theta(t-t')\frac1{\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\gamma^2}}e^{-\gamma t}\sin[\sqrt{\omega_0^2-\gamma^2}(t-t')],$$ where $\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function. With driving force $F(t)$, the solution is then $\int_0^tG(t,t') F(t')dt'$. One can also get the solution from the inverse FT of $\tilde{G}\tilde{F}$.   My question is:  why doesn't this Fourier integral naturally yield $0$ for $t<0$?  For instance, with $F(t)=\cos\omega t$, integrating directly over the $\delta$ functions in $\tilde{F}$ (rather than by contour integration) gives the steady state solution, valid for all $t$ positive and negative.

At first I just assumed it was a pole-skirting issue -- but both poles are in the UHP.  What am I overlooking?

Comment: Consider to include relevant calculations.